# Server side pdf generation and email

Tags: email, pdf

This question has two parts, one regarding sending emails with attachments and one regarding server side pdf generation.

I'm making a web app where the user enters data into a form. At the end I want the user to enter his/her email and then a pdf will be generated and emailed to the user.

Any advice on how to generate the pdf server side?

Any advice on how to automatically send the generated pdf attached in an email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this site. It requires PHP.

http://www.fpdf.org

Sending by email:

http://www.fpdf.org/en/FAQ.php#q15

Answer (score 1):

It will help you get better answers if you indicate what tools/languages you are using because there are specific answers for specific platforms.  [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) might be useful to you regardless of what platform you are using (especially the cloud service) since it can be called from most environments.  You would upload a template to it, then your app can call the service to produce a PDF and email it to your destination(s).  You would send your data in the request, the email destinations, the output format and Docmosis would execute the merge and generate and deliver the document.  Please note I work for the company that created Docmosis.

I hope that helps.